# DB Collation different to Analysis Services Collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm installing **SQL Server 2016** and I need my DB collation to be backward compatible with previous Database setups.

Therefore, I have selected `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. This is fine as there is an option to allow this (See below):

[image]

However, when selecting Analysis Services, the option is not available:

[image]

I get a warning saying:

[image]

**Question:**
What is the impact of having this difference? Does it matter? If so what is the best solution to resolve this?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I would go ask in the specialist DBA stack exchange site - dba.stackexchange.com as this is more an admin question than a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/globalization-tips-and-best-practices-analysis-services), `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` for database engine and `Latin1_General_AS` for Analysis service are *compatible*.

> Each service has its own collation settings, with the database engine default set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and Analysis Services set to Latin1_General_AS. The defaults are compatible in term of case, width, and accent sensitivity. Be forewarned that if you vary the settings of either collation, you can run into problems when the collation properties diverge in fundamental ways.